# Dynamic object keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Im trying to create an dynamic object with dynamic keys eg:

```
var test = "test";
var obj = {
    test:"bananas"
}
```

But I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`
Is this not allowed? anyway to do this? It's a must in my software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
obj[test + "ing"] = "bananas";
```

In relation to your edit:

```
var test = "test";
var obj = {};
obj[test] = "bananas";
```

or shorter:

```
var obj={[test]:"bananas"};
```

I normally wrap this in something like:

```
Object.expander = function(name, value, obj)
{
    obj = obj || {};
    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
};

var obj = Object.expander(test, "bananas");
```

Comment: what if i only had a variable `test`, no `+`, how can I get the string convert, same way only?

Comment: Just the same as with the '+', added another (verbose) snippet to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can't this way

try this instead

```
   obj["testing"] = "bananas"
```

Comment: this doesn't use his `test` variable -_-

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: yep, obviously. my point was to show how to dynamically create a key, not the way you build such a key.